# Do page transitions with AnimatePresense on exit work with Next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have been trying to implement `framer-motion` exit animations on a `Next JS 13` project with the new app router,

`AnimatePresense` does work but not on exit animations it seems like the `mode="wait"` is either broken or I am doing it wrong

my app directories

```
app
  - layout.tsx
  - page.tsx
  - projects
  -- project
  --- page.tsx
```

what I have tried:

** I have added `AnimatePresense` to `app/layout.tsx` like this

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AnimatePresence mode="wait">{children}</AnimatePresence>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

** added animations to `app/page.tsx`

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 3 } }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 5 } }}
className="grid gap-4 grid-cols-[repeat(1,minmax(400px,_1fr))] grid-rows-[repeat(4,minmax(400px,_1fr))] items-center justify-center"
    >
      <Link href="/projects/project">project page</Link>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

** added animations to `app/prjects/project/page.tsx`

```
const Project = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 3 } }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 5 } }}
      className="h-20 w-full bg-black text-white"
    >
      <Link href="/">back</Link>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

also I tried adding `app/template.tsx` instead of `app/layout.tsx` as Next docs recommend this for page transitions

```
const Template: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">{children}</AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

still not working, any recommendations ?

Comment: looking into it if i find something i will surely answer it

Comment: have you tried adding key to the components?

Comment: Exit animations
AnimatePresence works by detecting when direct children are removed from the React tree.

Any motion components contained by the removed child that have an exit prop will fire that animation before the entire tree is finally removed from the DOM.

Note: Direct children must each have a unique key prop so AnimatePresence can track their presence in the tree.

Comment: I tried adding key prop now still does not do the exit animation :/

Comment: try exitBeforeEnter Prop as well

Comment: it is deprecated and throws an error

Comment: probably it is broken, after checking the react component tree the component that has the animations is not being rendered as a direct child to `AnimatePresence` due to Next JS rendering more component after the template which we cannot control

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, using Framer Motion for "page exit" animations does not currently work in Next.js 13 with the app directory.

There are threads about it in both the Next.js repo issues and Framer repo issues:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49279
- https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1850